# How to return if an error occurs inside a `try-catch` block, and still run code in finally?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to exit the function if an error occurs inside the `try` block, and still run cleanup code in `finally`.

I'm doing it by using `shouldContinue` that is set to `true` initially, and set it to `false` inside the catch block if the execution shouldn't continue.

```
async uploadToServer() {
    let response;
    let shouldContinue = true;

    try {
        response = await this.uploderService.uploadFileToServer();

    } catch (error) {
        this.displayUploadError(error);
        shouldContinue = false;

    } finally {
        // run cleanup code anyway
        this.resetSession();
    }

    if (!shouldContinue) {
        return;
    }

    this.saveResponse(response);
    // continue execution here
    // ...

}
```

Is there a better way to exit the function after an error occurs inside the `try` block and still run code in `finally`?

Comment: Looks like you should just `return` in the `catch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (probably my personal preferred way) is to simply put everything inside the try (if possible - e.g. if nothing else inside the try could throw an unrelated error):

```js
async uploadToServer() {

    try {
        const response = await this.uploderService.uploadFileToServer();
        this.saveResponse(response);
        // continue execution here
        // ...
    } catch (error) {
        this.displayUploadError(error);
    } finally {
        // run cleanup code anyway
        this.resetSession();
    }

}
```

Another way is to return in the catch (finally still runs):

```
async uploadToServer() {
    let response;

    try {
        response = await this.uploderService.uploadFileToServer();
    } catch (error) {
        this.displayUploadError(error);
        return;
    } finally {
        // run cleanup code anyway
        this.resetSession();
    }

    this.saveResponse(response);
    // continue execution here
    // ...

}
```

Comment: I need to run the code inside finally before return inside the catch

Comment: @RonEvans that's not how `finally` works. It will always run _after_ the try & catch.

Comment: @RonEvans  Is this because you want to run `this.resetSession` before `this.displayUploadError`?..  If the order does not matter,  the return won't stop the finally been called..  If the order does matter, just do another level for try / finally or catch..

Comment: @Adam, I'd prefer your second function, as the rest of the function is complex and has other `try-catch` blocks, and wrapping everything in a `try-catch` block (a) makes me use nested try-catch blocks that I'm trying to avoid, and (b)has performance implications (wrapping all the code inside try-catch when not necessary )

Answer (score 1):

Finally will be executed anyway, either the try executed or catch.
Check the description in the link below for more information.

[Mozilla developer reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edit the answer and included a reference link for more details.